# How can I randomly delete a set number of characters from a file?

Tags: python, r, bash, fasta

I am trying to **randomly** remove 10%, 15% and 20% of the nucleotides in a fasta file.

So let's say I have a fasta file like this...

```
>GCA_900186885_1_000000000001
ATGCAAACATTTGTAAAAAACTTAATCGAT
```

I want to randomly choose and delete 10% of the nucleotides, which in this case would be 3, resulting in a fasta file with the same header, but with 3 fewer nucleotides:

```
>GCA_900186885_1_000000000001
ATGAAACATTGTAAAAACTTAATCGAT
```

The above is a simple example, which could easily be done manually, but I have a large fasta file with 2132142 nucleotides and thus want to generate three new fasta files using the original, but with 1918928, 1812321, and 1705714 nucleotides, representing a 10%, 15% and 20% reduction.

I have searched forums like stackoverflow and biostars for some related questions, but have not found **anything** useful.

I tried the following adaptation of a suggestion from another user to randomly delete lines from a file, but it didn't work.

```
filename=/Users/home/DETECTION/GCA_900186885.1_48903_D01_genomic_reformatted.fa
number=1918928

NT_count="$(grep -v ">" $filename | grep -E -o "G|C|T|A|N" | wc -l)"
NT_nums_to_delete="$(shuf -i "1-$NT_count" -n "$number")"
sed_script="$(printf '%dd;' $NT_nums_to_delete)"
sed -i.bak -e "$sed_script" "$filename"
```

The sed_script="$(printf '%dd;' $NT_nums_to_delete)" command resulted in the following error that I could not figure out.

```
zsh: bad math expression: operator expected at `2122589\n98...'
```

Any insight would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, as a biologist, why are you trying to do this?

Comment: The ultimate goal is to test the performance of a genome detection method that I am trying to design. I will take synthetic reads that were generated from the orginal fasta file and map them to these "reduced" reference genomes.

Comment: for clarification purposes ... define 'nucleotides' (any of the `A`, `C`, `G` or `T` letters?) ... are you looking to delete 10%/15%/20% from each line in the file, or could some lines end up with more deletions than other lines?

Comment: Yes, nucleotides in this context refers to any A, C, T or G. In this particular fasta file there is technically only two lines, one with the header info ">GCA_900186885_1_000000000001" and the second a long string of As, Ts, Cs, and Gs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you tagged bash, here's one in awk:

```
$ awk -v s=$RANDOM 'BEGIN {
    if(s)                                      # if seed provided as var s
        srand(s)                               # use s as seed 
    else                                       # or not
        srand()
}
!/^>/ {                                        # process non > starting records
    i=int(0.1*(length($0)))                    # 10 % of length to remove
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++) {
        p=int(rand()*length($0))+1             # p the point from where to remove
        $0=substr($0,1,(p-1)) substr($0,(p+1)) # ie. skip p:s char 
    }
}
1' file                                        # output
```

Sample output:

```
>GCA_900186885_1_000000000001
ATGCAAACATGTAAAAAACTTAACGAT
```

Answer (score 0):

20% independent indels sounds like a much higher rate than would be biologically relevant.
You specified that your independent deletions happen at
the nucleotide level rather than the 3-base codon level,
and you didn't mention any repair / resync / exon detection.

Here are your three example deletions:

```bash
ATGCAAACATTTGTAAAAAACTTAATCGAT
ATG AAACATT GTAAAAA CTTAATCGAT
```

They look like they're independent of one another,
no clumping.

---

For the 30-base example you offered, we might do this:

```
from random import seed, shuffle
seed(42)  # arbitrary value, for reproducibility across runs
bases = list('ATGCAAACATTTGTAAAAAACTTAATCGAT')
idx = list(range(len(bases)))
shuffle(idx)
num_deletions = int(.10 * len(bases))  # 3
for i in idx[:num_deletions]:
    del bases[i]
return ''.join(bases)
```

Permuting the indexes and deleting the first 3 is very simple,
but it has quadratic performance so you wouldn't want to run it
on two million bases.

Here's the same thing with linear performance:

```
...
deletions = set(idx[:num_deletions])
for i, base in enumerate(bases):
    if i not in deletions:
        yield base
```

This still has the downside of allocating two million integers.

So you would probably prefer to delete *approximately* the
right number of bases:

```
seed(42)
for base in bases:
    if random() >= .1:
        yield base
```

To get *exactly* the right number we would need to
dynamically adjust that .1 according to whether the output string
is looking too long or too short ATM.
In practice it would be simpler to proceed in chunks,
finishing up with the exact shuffle approach on some
conveniently small number of bases at the end.

Comment: The deletions aren't meant to be biologically meaningful indels. Thank you for your effort. I ended up using the bash approach suggested by James Brown. It was simple and fast.